# How can I use the repositories from my web project in another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a website built in asp.net mvc 3 which uses the repository pattern and EF.
I have added another project to my solution and would like to access the repositories from within this project for the database work.

I have added a reference to my web project from my new project but when I try and instance a repository I get the error:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

I'm guessing that EF doesnt like to be called outside of the project that it is configured for.

Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET will use the Web.Config or App.Config from the startup project for configuration.  You need to copy the connection strings (and any other necessary settings) into your new project for your database connections to work.

It is also a best practice to move the Repositories and .edmx file into a separate project so your new application does not depend on the entire Web project being correct before it works.  You can create a new Class Library project in your solution, drag the Model folder in there, and then add a reference to this project in both your mvc 3 site and your new application.